# Keep running into "exceeded its progress dead line" despite changing progressDeadlineSeconds

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-namespace

I'm new AKS, ACR, and DevOps Pipelines and I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline.

I have a resource group setup that has both AKS and ACR in it. AKS is using `Standard_B2s` and only one node at this point since I'm just playing around.

Images are being deployed to ACR automatically on a commit to master--haven't figured out how to setup testing yet--but when it comes to deploying to AKS, I just keep getting a:

```
##[error]error: deployment "client-deployment" exceeded its progress deadline
```

I've changed my `client.yaml` to include a `progressDeadlineSeconds` of like an hour as 10, 15, and 20 minutes didn't work:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 3600
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: testappcontainers.azurecr.io/testapp-client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: client
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

I've just been modifying the `azure-pipelines.yml` that Pipelines generated for me, which I currently have as the following:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: <dockerRegistryServiceConnection_key>
  imageRepository: 'testapp'
  containerRegistry: 'testappcontainers.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: <imagePullSecret_key>

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push client image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)-client
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/client/Dockerfile
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy job
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'testapp.default'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/client.yaml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

Here is the log too for the Task that fails:

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy to Kubernetes cluster'
##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
##[section]Starting: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
==============================================================================
Task         : Deploy to Kubernetes
Description  : Use Kubernetes manifest files to deploy to clusters or even bake the manifest files to be used for deployments using Helm charts
Version      : 0.162.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest
==============================================================================
##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading INPUT_ACTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_KUBERNETESSERVICECONNECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_STRATEGY
##[debug]loading INPUT_TRAFFICSPLITMETHOD
##[debug]loading INPUT_PERCENTAGE
##[debug]loading INPUT_BASELINEANDCANARYREPLICAS
##[debug]loading INPUT_MANIFESTS
##[debug]loading INPUT_CONTAINERS
##[debug]loading INPUT_IMAGEPULLSECRETS
##[debug]loading INPUT_RENDERTYPE
##[debug]loading INPUT_DOCKERCOMPOSEFILE
##[debug]loading INPUT_HELMCHART
##[debug]loading INPUT_KUSTOMIZATIONPATH
##[debug]loading INPUT_RESOURCETOPATCH
##[debug]loading INPUT_RESOURCEFILETOPATCH
##[debug]loading INPUT_MERGESTRATEGY
##[debug]loading INPUT_SECRETTYPE
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_<token>
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_<token>
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_AZUREENVIRONMENT
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_AZURETENANTID
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_SERVICEACCOUNTNAME
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_ROLEBINDINGNAME
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_SECRETNAME
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_APITOKEN
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_<token>_SERVICEACCOUNTCERTIFICATE
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading SECRET_CONTAINER_PASSWORD
##[debug]loading SECRET_CONTAINER_USERNAME
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 32
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE=build
##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://dev.azure.com/thetestcompany/
##[debug]Build.BuildNumber=20191231.5
##[debug]Build.DefinitionName=test-app
##[debug]System.DefinitionId=4
##[debug]Agent.JobName=Deploy job
##[debug]System.TeamProject=test-app
##[debug]Build.BuildId=41
##[debug]System.TeamProject=test-app
##[debug]namespace=null
##[debug]containers=***/testapp:41
##[debug]imagePullSecrets=testappcontainers<key>-auth
##[debug]manifests=/home/vsts/work/1/manifests/client.yaml
##[debug]percentage=0
##[debug]strategy=none
##[debug]trafficSplitMethod=pod
##[debug]baselineAndCanaryReplicas=0
##[debug]arguments=null
##[debug]secretArguments=null
##[debug]secretType=dockerRegistry
##[debug]secretName=null
##[debug]dockerRegistryEndpoint=null
##[debug]kubernetesServiceConnection=<token>
##[debug]<token> data namespace = default
##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://dev.azure.com/thetestcompany/
##[debug]System.HostType=build
##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=/home/vsts/work/1/s
##[debug]Build.SourceBranchName=master
##[debug]Build.Repository.Provider=TfsGit
##[debug]Build.Repository.Uri=https://thetestcompany@dev.azure.com/thetestcompany/test-app/_git/test-app
##[debug]agent.proxyurl=undefined
##[debug]VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS=undefined
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_<hash>_build_4_0
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]check path : /home/vsts/work/_tasks/KubernetesManifest_<hash>/0.162.1/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tool-lib/lib.json
##[debug]adding resource file: /home/vsts/work/_tasks/KubernetesManifest_<hash>/0.162.1/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tool-lib/lib.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]check path : /home/vsts/work/_tasks/KubernetesManifest_<hash>/0.162.1/task.json
##[debug]adding resource file: /home/vsts/work/_tasks/KubernetesManifest_<hash>/0.162.1/task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]action=deploy
##[debug]kubernetesServiceConnection=<token>
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]<token> data authorizationType = AzureSubscription
##[debug]<token>=https://testappk8s-dns-<key>.hcp.westus.azmk8s.io/
##[debug]<token> auth param serviceAccountCertificate = ***
##[debug]<token> auth param apiToken = ***
##[debug]set KUBECONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1577816701759/config
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=KUBECONFIG;issecret=false;]/home/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1577816701759/config
##[debug]<token> data acceptUntrustedCerts = undefined
##[debug]which 'kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]which 'kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=/home/vsts/work/1/s
##[debug]defaultRoot: '/home/vsts/work/1/s'
##[debug]findOptions.allowBrokenSymbolicLinks: 'false'
##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
##[debug]pattern: '/home/vsts/work/1/manifests/client.yaml'
##[debug]findPath: '/home/vsts/work/1/manifests/client.yaml'
##[debug]statOnly: 'true'
##[debug]found 1 paths
##[debug]applying include pattern
##[debug]1 matches
##[debug]1 final results
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]New K8s objects after addin imagePullSecrets are :[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"name":"client-deployment"},"spec":{"progressDeadlineSeconds":3600,"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"component":"client"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"component":"client"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"client","image":"***/testapp-client","ports":[{"containerPort":3000}]}],"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"testappcontainers1741032e-auth"}]}}}},{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"name":"client-cluster-ip-service"},"spec":{"type":"ClusterIP","selector":{"component":"client"},"ports":[{"port":3000,"targetPort":3000}]}}]
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: apply
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["-f","/home/vsts/work/_temp/Deployment_client-deployment_1577816701782,/home/vsts/work/_temp/Service_client-cluster-ip-service_1577816701782"]
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["--namespace","default"]
##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/kubectl
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   apply
##[debug]   -f
##[debug]   /home/vsts/work/_temp/Deployment_client-deployment_1577816701782,/home/vsts/work/_temp/Service_client-cluster-ip-service_1577816701782
##[debug]   --namespace
##[debug]   default
[command]/usr/bin/kubectl apply -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/Deployment_client-deployment_1577816701782,/home/vsts/work/_temp/Service_client-cluster-ip-service_1577816701782 --namespace default
deployment.apps/client-deployment unchanged
service/client-cluster-ip-service unchanged
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["rollout","status"]
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: Deployment/client-deployment
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["--namespace","default"]
##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/kubectl
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   rollout
##[debug]   status
##[debug]   Deployment/client-deployment
##[debug]   --namespace
##[debug]   default
[command]/usr/bin/kubectl rollout status Deployment/client-deployment --namespace default
error: deployment "client-deployment" exceeded its progress deadline
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]which '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/kubectl'
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: get
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: service/client-cluster-ip-service
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["-o","json"]
##[debug]/usr/bin/kubectl arg: ["--namespace","default"]
##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/kubectl
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   get
##[debug]   service/client-cluster-ip-service
##[debug]   -o
##[debug]   json
##[debug]   --namespace
##[debug]   default
[command]/usr/bin/kubectl get service/client-cluster-ip-service -o json --namespace default
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"client-cluster-ip-service\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":3000,\"targetPort\":3000}],\"selector\":{\"component\":\"client\"},\"type\":\"ClusterIP\"}}\n"
        },
        "creationTimestamp":         "name": "client-cluster-ip-service",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "1234045",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/client-cluster-ip-service",
        "uid": "5f077159-2bdd-11ea-af20-3eaa105eb2b3"
    },
    "spec": {
        "clusterIP": "10.0.181.220",
        "ports": [
            {
                "port": 3000,
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "targetPort": 3000
            }
        ],
        "selector": {
            "component": "client"
        },
        "sessionAffinity": "None",
        "type": "ClusterIP"
    },
    "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {}
    }
}
##[debug]KUBECONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1577816701759/config
##[debug]set KUBECONFIG=
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=KUBECONFIG;issecret=false;]
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]error: deployment "client-deployment" exceeded its progress deadline
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]error: deployment "client-deployment" exceeded its progress deadline
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]error: deployment "client-deployment" exceeded its progress deadline
##[section]Finishing: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
```

Then in Azure CLI, it shows the deployment is there, but with no available pods:

```
eox-dev@Azure:~$ kubectl get deployments
NAME                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
client-deployment   0/1     1            0           3h47m
eox-dev@Azure:~$ kubectl describe deployment client-deployment
Name:                   client-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 31 Dec 2019 15:50:30 +0000
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                          {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"client-deployment","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"progre...
Selector:               component=client
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  component=client
  Containers:
   client:
    Image:        testappcontainers.azurecr.io/testapp-client
    Port:         3000/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   client-deployment-5688bdc69c (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your deployed container "client-deployment" fails to start... can you paste the logs from this container?

Comment: Ok, that was much more informative than what I've been looking at: `Error from server (BadRequest): container "client" in pod "client-deployment-5688bdc69c-hxlcf" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image`... looks like it is failing to pull the image for some reason. At least now I have something to go on besides a non-descriptive error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Error from server (BadRequest): container "client" in pod
>   "client-deployment-5688bdc69c-hxlcf" is waiting to start: trying and
>   failing to pull image

Based on my experience, this is more relative with `imagePullSecrets` and the `Kubernetes namespace`.

In your `Create imagePullSecret` and `Deploy to Kubernetes cluster` task, I saw that you did not provide the value to task parameter: `namespace`. This will lead to a new namespace which name is `default`  will be created, since you **unspecified** the namespace.

And, the [kubernetes secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-security#kubernetes-secrets) which generated by `createSecret` action is seperated for each namespace. In one word, different namespace has different secret value:

> Secrets are stored within a given namespace and can only be accessed
>   by pods within the same namespace.

---

Now, let’s back to your build compile process.

In your yml definition, `Create imagePullSecret` will create a `secret` for new namespace `default` which created by task automatically as you did not provide the given namespace value.

Then, in next task `Deploy to Kubernetes cluster`, because of the same reason, here the task will re-created a another new namespace `default`(**Note:** this is not same with the previous one). Also, you could see this progress from the log:

[image]

At this time, the `secret` that generated from the previous task will not available for the current namespace. BUT, as you know, the `ACR` is a private container registry which our system must verify whether the `kubernetes secret` is available.

In addition, in your Deploy to Kubernetes cluster task, you were specifying the repository as `$(imageRepository)` which does not same with the repository you push the image to **`$(imageRepository)-client`**.

This can also be checked in your log:

[image]

That's why there's no available node in your kubernetes, and you failed to pull the image also.

---

To avoid the issue, please ensure you provide the `namespace` value in `KubernetesManifest@0` task.

```
      - task: KubernetesManifest@0
        displayName: Create imagePullSecret
        inputs:
          action: createSecret
          secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
          namespace: $(k8sNamespace)
          dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(DRServiceConnection)

      - task: KubernetesManifest@0
        displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
        inputs:
          action: deploy
          namespace: $(k8sNamespace)
          manifests: |
            $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yml
          imagePullSecrets: |
            $(imagePullSecret)
          containers: |
            $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository)-client:$(tag)
```

secret to imagePullSecrets of each namespace

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issues even provided the namespace still get error 
"exceeded its progress deadline
 Waiting for deployment "XX-service" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available..."

due to fail to pull image

Adding 
"imagePullPolicy: Always" in .yaml fixed my rollout pull issues

Comment: sometime in my project delete and deployment takes time to process and create new should be done after adding some time, and  "Deployment strategy: Canary"

Answer (score 3):

I think what is likely to cause this issue (particularly in AKS) is if your cluster runs a health check or a liveness check on your containers before deploying.
Your cluster identifies that your application isn't running and enters a waiting state due to CrashLoopBackOff

This can be fixed by just creating a default GET route on your API application on "/" that returns a 200. This will indicate that your containers are healthy or live

Answer (score 1):

throwing my 2¢ in here for what happened with ours:

As it turns out, this error can show for just about any reason that would prevent the k8s cluster from running and/or *obtaining* a given image.

Our issue wasn't with our container, but fetching it from the container registry.

Just ran the following on the cluster to see there was an ImagePullBackoff issue and then ran another command to get more information:

```bash
kubectl get all --namespace=the-namespace-its-in # get all resources e.g. deployments, pods, etc

kubectl describe pods/my-imagepullbackoff-pod # Look at the events section at the bottom for more info!
```

After this we could confirm there was an issue pulling from the Azure Container Registry. To help prevent this in the future we're taking advantage of container registry features like [Zone Redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/zone-redundancy) and [Georeplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/zone-redundancy).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue because of an exception and also readiness probe failures. After solving those issues, rollout has been completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was issue with the worker node. So I just tried to pull the image from the node which my pod is assigned to. I came to know that the node is having some perfmance related issue so I just add a high new node with high spec and assigned the pod to that node. The deployment also got successful.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error, but in my case, I had not included some required modules in the requirements.txt for proper deployment.
For django, run `pip freeze -r requirements.txt`
Can also use other tools to fetch only the required imports, such as `pipreqs`

Answer (score 0):

Also came across this error, but in my case it was exceeding quota:

`Error creating: pods "my-service-dev-5898568fd8-jnx77" is forbidden:  exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: cpu=400m, used: cpu=6750m, limited: cpu=7`